# Unable to Execute Powershell Script in TeamCity

Tags: azure, teamcity

I have created a Powershell Build Runner in TeamCity to run the following code:

```
<# 
    Steps to run:
    1) Login to Azure
    2) Select correct subscription
    3) Alter the path below to where you have the have saved the pester test locally
#>

$pesterParamters = @{
    Path       = '**.ps1 => pesterproject2.%build.number%.zip'
    Parameters = @{
                     templateUri                 = "**.json => pesterproject2.%build.number%.zip"
                     templateParameterObject     = @{
                            resourcePrefix = "pester"
                            adminPassword  = "Patters0n1234"
                        }
                  } 
}

$parameterHash= @{
                     resourcePrefix = "pester"
                     adminPassword  = "Patters0n1234"
                 }

Invoke-Pester -Script $pesterParamters -OutputFile "+:*/*.Xml =>
pesterproject2.%build.number%.zip" -OutputFormat NUnitXml -PassThru
```

However the nothing is being sent to the output file/folder as an .xml

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for your Invoke-Perster -OutputFile syntax does not seems to be correct.

It seems that you would like to mix your Powershell code, and the TeamCity configuration.

You should modify your code to:

```
Invoke-Pester -Script $pesterParamters -OutputFile "MyOutput.Xml" -OutputFormat NUnitXml -PassThru
```

And inside the `Artifact paths` of TeamCity, you should set the:

```
*.xml => pesterproject2.%build.number%.zip
```